# Dynamic parameters for XSLT 2.0 group-by

Tags: dynamic, group-by, xslt-2.0, parameters

I got this input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>
  <datapoint poiid="2492" period="2004" value="1240"/>
  <datapoint poiid="2492" period="2005" value="1290"/>
  <datapoint poiid="2492" period="2006" value="1280"/>
  <datapoint poiid="2492" period="2007" value="1320"/>
  <datapoint poiid="2492" period="2008" value="1330"/>
  <datapoint poiid="2492" period="2009" value="1340"/>
  <datapoint poiid="2492" period="2010" value="1340"/>
  <datapoint poiid="2492" period="2011" value="1335"/>
  <datapoint poiid="2493" period="2004" value="1120"/>
  <datapoint poiid="2493" period="2005" value="1120"/>
  <datapoint poiid="2493" period="2006" value="1100"/>
  <datapoint poiid="2493" period="2007" value="1100"/>
  <datapoint poiid="2493" period="2008" value="1100"/>
  <datapoint poiid="2493" period="2009" value="1110"/>
  <datapoint poiid="2493" period="2010" value="1105"/>
  <datapoint poiid="2493" period="2011" value="1105"/>
</result>
```

and I use this xslt 2.0

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">


    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="result">

        <xsl:for-each-group select="datapoint" group-by="@poiid">
            <node type="poiid" id="{@poiid}">
                <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                    <node type="period" id="{@period}" value="{@value}"/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </node>

        </xsl:for-each-group>

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to convert it into

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<node type="poiid" id="2492">
   <node type="period" id="2004" value="1240"/>
   <node type="period" id="2005" value="1290"/>
   <node type="period" id="2006" value="1280"/>
   <node type="period" id="2007" value="1320"/>
   <node type="period" id="2008" value="1330"/>
   <node type="period" id="2009" value="1340"/>
   <node type="period" id="2010" value="1340"/>
   <node type="period" id="2011" value="1335"/>
</node>
<node type="poiid" id="2493">
   <node type="period" id="2004" value="1120"/>
   <node type="period" id="2005" value="1120"/>
   <node type="period" id="2006" value="1100"/>
   <node type="period" id="2007" value="1100"/>
   <node type="period" id="2008" value="1100"/>
   <node type="period" id="2009" value="1110"/>
   <node type="period" id="2010" value="1105"/>
   <node type="period" id="2011" value="1105"/>
</node>
```

Works smoothly.

Where I got stuck is when I tried to make it more dynamic. The real life input has 6 attributes for each datapoint instead of 3, and the usecase requires the possibility to set the grouping parameters dynamically.

I tried using parameters

```
    <xsl:param name="k1" select="'poiid'"/>
    <xsl:param name="k2" select="'period'"/>
```

but passing them to the rest of the xslt is something that I can't get right. The code below doesn't work, but clarifies hopefully, what I'm looking for.

```
    <xsl:template match="result">

        <xsl:for-each-group select="datapoint" group-by="@{$k1}">
            <node type="{$k1}" id="@{$k1}">
                <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                    <node type="{$k2}" id="@{$k2}" value="{@value}"/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </node>

        </xsl:for-each-group>

    </xsl:template>
```

Any help appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is how to do it**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

 <xsl:param name="k1" select="'poiid'"/>
 <xsl:param name="k2" select="'period'"/>

 <xsl:template match="result">
   <xsl:for-each-group select="datapoint" group-by="@*[name()= $k1]">
     <node type="{$k1}" id="{@*[name() = $k1]}">
       <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
         <node type="{k2}" id="{@*[name()= $k2]}" value="{@value}"/>
       </xsl:for-each>
     </node>
   </xsl:for-each-group>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<result>
    <datapoint poiid="2492" period="2004" value="1240"/>
    <datapoint poiid="2492" period="2005" value="1290"/>
    <datapoint poiid="2492" period="2006" value="1280"/>
    <datapoint poiid="2492" period="2007" value="1320"/>
    <datapoint poiid="2492" period="2008" value="1330"/>
    <datapoint poiid="2492" period="2009" value="1340"/>
    <datapoint poiid="2492" period="2010" value="1340"/>
    <datapoint poiid="2492" period="2011" value="1335"/>
    <datapoint poiid="2493" period="2004" value="1120"/>
    <datapoint poiid="2493" period="2005" value="1120"/>
    <datapoint poiid="2493" period="2006" value="1100"/>
    <datapoint poiid="2493" period="2007" value="1100"/>
    <datapoint poiid="2493" period="2008" value="1100"/>
    <datapoint poiid="2493" period="2009" value="1110"/>
    <datapoint poiid="2493" period="2010" value="1105"/>
    <datapoint poiid="2493" period="2011" value="1105"/>
</result>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<node type="poiid" id="2492">
   <node type="" id="2004" value="1240"/>
   <node type="" id="2005" value="1290"/>
   <node type="" id="2006" value="1280"/>
   <node type="" id="2007" value="1320"/>
   <node type="" id="2008" value="1330"/>
   <node type="" id="2009" value="1340"/>
   <node type="" id="2010" value="1340"/>
   <node type="" id="2011" value="1335"/>
</node>
<node type="poiid" id="2493">
   <node type="" id="2004" value="1120"/>
   <node type="" id="2005" value="1120"/>
   <node type="" id="2006" value="1100"/>
   <node type="" id="2007" value="1100"/>
   <node type="" id="2008" value="1100"/>
   <node type="" id="2009" value="1110"/>
   <node type="" id="2010" value="1105"/>
   <node type="" id="2011" value="1105"/>
</node>
```

Comment: Dimitre, the group-by="@poiid" being not dynamic and an alternative like group-by="{@*[name()=$k1]}"  being invalid. I'm still stuck :(  Other parts of your solution provided useful insights however. Thanks

Comment: Ophileon, the `group-by` attribute is already an XPath expression so don't use curly braces in there, simply use `group-by="@*[name() = $k1]"`. That way Dimitre's suggestion should do what you want.

Comment: @Ophileon, Yes, these were in so many places that I overlooked one. Fixed now.